# How do I look for the following value in list using regex:

Tags: python, regex, list

I have the following string list:

```
['0        NaT\n5     7 days\n10    5 days\n14    2 days\n23   12 days\n24    1 days\n27    1 days\n30    2 days\n31    1 days\n32    1 days\n34    4 days\n36   25 days\n42   30 days\n43    2 days\n44    1     days\n46    2 days\n51    5 days']
```

I need to look for instances where this sequence is present and extract the number in between:

```
Look for '1 days\n{some number}    1 days\'

Example from list:
1 days\n27    1 days\

Number is:
27
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in regex? If there is another method without using regex please teach me that as well.

Comment: An array containing one string, right? Why not just the string? The horizontally scrolling needed to read your string hurt my shoulder. Could you have used a shorter one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is likely the best way.

```
import re
result = [ re.findall(r'\b1 days\\n(\d+)\s+1 days', x, ) for x in your_list ]
```

Comment: How are you going to distinquish between 1 and 11 or 1 and 21 etc... This would work for the sample data but something more generic would be better =). Just a headsup. Oh yeah, you would want to use raw strings to make the backslashes literal.

Comment: @JvdV right. Corrected.

Comment: Not sure if you knew, but I'll edit your pattern a little...